# Extracting a process's icon from a UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

How do I get a process's associated Icon from a C# UWP application?

I am currently in the process of porting a WPF application to UWP and unfortunately found that system.drawing isn't apart of the UWP SDK.

In my WPF program, I used `Bitmap Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(process.MainModule.FileName).ToBitmap();` to extract the icon but this no longer works.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get a process's associated Icon from a C# UWP application?

In UWP, you could use [AppDiagnosticInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appdiagnosticinfo) relevant APIs to get the application's logo.

Locate to the specific method is the [AppDisplayInfo.GetLogo(Size) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appdisplayinfo.getlogo#Windows_ApplicationModel_AppDisplayInfo_GetLogo_Windows_Foundation_Size_).

You couuld see the complete steps in this blog [UWP App Diagnostics](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/#vXyVYfxjW5esHEK0.97).

Please note that if your app uses these APIs, you’ll need to declare the `appDiagnostics` capability in your manifest.